# javascript function will not fire - cannot determine why

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session

I am trying to create a search system where users can return to a previously made search. In order to do this I am using php sessions to recreate their search whenever they return to the search page. Because the function that actually does the search is in javascript, I am having to use Ajax to post the appropriate variables to into the session in PHP and then return it to javascript variables to refire the search function.

However, when I try to use those session variables (passed into javascript) to re fire the search function (and so present the same results again) the function will not fire, but the same function will fire normally i.e. for the original search. I have checked and all the variables are the same so I cannot tell why the function will not fire.

I know it's not a problem with the function as the original search works no problem. Here is my code. Please help.

Javascript

```
var sessSubj = '<?php echo $_SESSION['subject'];?>';
var sessLevel = '<?php echo $_SESSION['level'];?>';
var sessTopic = '<?php echo $_SESSION['topic'];?>';
var sessAddress = '<?php echo $_SESSION['address'];?>';
var sessSort = '<?php echo $_SESSION['sort'];?>';

if (sessLevel != "" && sessSubj != "") {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        address: sessAddress
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            center = results[0].geometry.location;
            searchLocationsNear(center, sessLevel, sessSubj, sessTopic, sessSort);
        }
    });
}

function searchLocationsNear(center, level, subject, topic, sort) {
    clearLocations();
    if ($('div.pages')) {
        $('div.pages').remove()
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "findlocations.php",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            "level": level,
             "subject": subject,
             "topic": topic,
             "lat": center.lat(),
             "lng": center.lng(),
             "radius": 20,
             "sort": sort
        },
        success: function (data, response) { /* do stuff*/
        }
```

Comment: I think some debugging is in order. Does the console show any error when trying to use the search function like that?

Comment: Are you in a "$(document).ready()"? And even so, maybe the google API is not loaded yet at the moment you call the search. Check that by pressing f12 and going into the console section.  Must be written something like "google is not defined"

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - it was a problem with a couple of other functions that just needed a break and fresh look.